# How to find the path to a .txt file in glassfish v3.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

In my aplication i want to send a html template to the users email. Everithing works correctly when i programatically create the html, but what i want to do now, is read the html text from within a file in my application and send it. I get a FileNotFoundException, and i dont know how to find that .txt file. See the code:

```
public void sendAccountActivationLinkToBuyer(String destinationEmail,
        String name) {

    // Destination of the email
    String to = destinationEmail;
    String from = "myEmail@gmail.com";

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        // From: is our service
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        // To: destination given
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Registration succeded");
        // Instead of simple text, a .html template should be added here!
        message.setText(generateActivationLinkTemplate());

        Date timeStamp = new Date();
        message.setSentDate(timeStamp);

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

private String generateActivationLinkTemplate() {
    String htmlText = "";

    try {
        File f = new File("");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./web/emailActivationTemplate.txt")));
        String content = "";
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content += line;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return htmlText;
}
```

The second method is giving me problems, i cant find that .txt file. What should i do?
I created the folder web inside the WebContent folder,the web folder is now located right next to META-INF and WEB-INF(I think that is an appropiate place to hold my images, templates,css...) Inside the folder i manually pasted the emailActivationTemplate.txt Now i need to read from it. Any ideas?

This is the console output:

> SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\web\emailActivationTemplate.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Where exactly have you placed the file `emailActivationTemplate.txt`? Can you give me the full path of that file starting from the AppServer root?

Comment: Currently in C:\jee6workspace\BBS\WebContent\web\emailActivationTemplate.txt
I rode that the .css files, images... should go in that folder. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah saw that after I posted the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put emailActivationTemplate.txt in WEB-INF/classes, and get it with

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("emailActivationTemplate.txt"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(String) System.getProperties().get("com.sun.aas.instanceRoot")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `emailActivationTemplate.txt` should be present inside the `classes` folder of `WEB-INF`. If you manage to place it there, you should be able to read it using:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/emailActivationTemplate.txt")));
```

Try without the leading '/' if it doesn't work.

Comment: Does not work this is the output: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:61)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:55)
 at ejbs.EmailServiceEJB.generateActivationLinkTemplate(EmailServiceEJB.java:60)
 at ejbs.EmailServiceEJB.sendAccountActivationLinkToBuyer(EmailServiceEJB.java:43)