# javamail adding images to html emails. How?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jakarta-mail, java-ee-6

I am sending emails with javamail with no problem(I use EJB 3.0), the problem is when i try to add some image to the html, by ussing a multipart approach. For some reason i get a FileNotFoundException. I dont know how to get the path to the .png image that is located at WEB-INF/resources/images.

Here is what i did:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        // From: is our service
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        // To: destination given
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Uspijesna registracija");
        // How to found at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0321.html
        message.setContent(generateActivationLinkTemplate(), "text/html");

        Date timeStamp = new Date();
        message.setSentDate(timeStamp);

        // Prepare a multipart HTML
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        // Prepare the HTML
        BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(generateActivationLinkTemplate(), "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        // PREPARE THE IMAGE
        BodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("logomailtemplate.png");
        imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
        imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "the-img-1");
        multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
        // Set the message content!
        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(message);
```

The text is coming from another method, that works correctly. I think the problem is in this line of code:

> DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("logomailtemplate.png");

This is what the console says:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: logomailtemplate.png (The system cannot find the file specified)

How can i access that image? It is located in WEB-INF/resources/images
I am stuck the hold day with this ill really appreciate a hand :)

-----------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        // From: is our service
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        // To: destination given
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Uspijesna registracija");
        // How to found at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0321.html
        message.setContent(generateActivationLinkTemplate(), "text/html");

        Date timeStamp = new Date();
        message.setSentDate(timeStamp);

        // Prepare a multipart HTML
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        // Prepare the HTML
        BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(generateActivationLinkTemplate(), "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        // PREPARE THE IMAGE
        BodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        String fileName = "WEB-INF/resources/images/logoemailtemplate.png";
        InputStream stream = null;
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        if (classLoader == null) {
            classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        }
        stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(stream, "image/*");             

        imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
        imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "the-img-1");
        multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
        // Set the message content!
        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(message);
```

------------------------------------------STACK TRACE-----------------------------------

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
>       ................
>
> SEVERE: javax.ejb.EJBException
>   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
>       at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>       at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5119)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5017)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4805)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2004)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
>       at $Proxy162.sendAccountActivationLinkToBuyer(Unknown Source)
>       at managedbeans.RegistrationController.doRegisterBuyer(RegistrationController.java:64)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
>       at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:72)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
>       at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>       ... 32 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource.(ByteArrayDataSource.java:83)
>       at ejbs.EmailServiceEJB.sendAccountActivationLinkToBuyer(EmailServiceEJB.java:69)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1056)
>       at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1128)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5292)
>       at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
>       at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
>       at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
>       at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5264)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5252)
>       at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
>       ... 45 more

-----------------------------------UPDATE 2-----------------------------------------

```
String fileName = "/WEB-INF/resources/images/logoemailtemplate.png";
        InputStream stream = null;
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        if (classLoader == null) {
            classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        }
        //This line dont work!
        stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);                                                 


        DataSource ds = new    URLDataSource(classLoader.getResource(fileName));
```

> //DataSource ds = new FileDataSource(new File(classLoader
>   //                  .getResource(fileName).toURI())); Also dont work. Also i tried both / and without /

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the path to a .txt file in glassfish v3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246472/how-to-find-the-path-to-a-txt-file-in-glassfish-v3-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of accomplishing this can be:

```
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/resources/images/logomailtemplate.png") ,mimeType);
```

`getServletContext().getResourceAsStream()` is received from a `HttpServlet` and returns an `InputStream`.

---

Better yet do this

```
String fileName = "/WEB-INF/resources/images/logomailtemplate.png";
InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(fileName); //or null if you can't obtain a ServletContext

if (stream == null) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (classLoader == null) {
        classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    }

    stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}

DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(stream, "image/*");
```

---

**Update**

Alternatively

```
String fileName = "WEB-INF/resources/images/logomailtemplate.png";
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
if (classLoader == null) {
    classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
}

DataSource ds = new FileDataSource(new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).toURI()));

//OR
DataSource ds = new URLDataSource(classLoader.getResource(fileName));
```

Make sure your `fileName` starts with "/".

Comment: `mimeType` will be your image mimetype (png will be `image/png`, if I'm not mistaken). See my updated post for further enhancements.

Comment: Then use `ClassLoader` then. `ServletContext` exists only within a `Servlet`.

Comment: I saw the update and i understand some how, but the method getServletContext() is not called by any object, where it comes from? Do i have to extend HTTPServlet or something like that to be able to use it?

Comment: As I said before, since you're not using Servlets, skip the `getServletContext()`. Just jump inside the `if` statement. Implement that only.

Comment: Sorry i did not scroll right so i did not rode that. The last line of code DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(stream, "image/*"); the first arg should be a Byte[], how can i cast it somehow

Comment: Could you tell me the package please, i see there are a few classes with that name, thats why does not compile. Your code is valid you are right

Comment: `javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource`. You should have it since you're using javamail

Comment: It compiles, but i get some kind of NullPointer here is a bit of the stackTrace:

Caused by: javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected MIME type, got null
Also i think that the parameter stream that i pass is making the problem, maybe the path is not correct?

Comment: I found one of the problems: 
The file name is logoemailtemplate.png that was miss spelled Now is correct The error is now with DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(stream, "image/*"); the passed object stream in null, but why?

Comment: Put the exception log on the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay i just posted the last bit of the stack in the question above

Comment: I just updated again sorry about that, i dont know how to post it all at once inside quotes(I am new in the forum since last week :) )

Comment: I think that the reason is that the path /WEB-INF/resources/images/logoemailtemplate.png is wrong. I dont know. What else could be?

Comment: I just tried again all combinations, but i still recieve the NullPointer. Check my UPDATE 2 in the question there you can see i did as you said

Comment: My best guess is that your EJB and your application is not running in the same application.

Comment: That is impossible this application is currently the only project in my eclipse Helios workspace.Also i mentioned in the question that i can perfectly send just html, so that means that the EJB is being used by the application(I dont think they are not running in the same app). I dont understand very well how class loader works but if the path is correct, it should return that image to create the other half of the multipart email :(

Comment: Debug and see if it returns anything.

Comment: after classLoader is setted i added a printMethod with a condition and it didnt print, that means it is not null 
classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    if (classLoader == null) {
     System.out.println("IT IS NULL AGAIN!!!!");
    } I am out of ideas

Comment: What debuger?, the one of eclipse? :) I dont really like that thing, but i will try :) anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: My friend i fixed the problem, by adding the image to the classes folder and not the resources, some other guy explained me in another post. Now my problem is that i recive an email with an image but i dont see the html table that was suposed to be there. Here is the other post if you want to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248276/javamail-adding-images-to-html-emails-how

Comment: Ups :) try this it is this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250704/cant-retrieve-an-images-from-the-web-inf-folder-ussing-classloader-getresourceass