# Cant retrieve an images from the WEB-INF folder ussing classLoader.getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0, jakarta-mail

The hold noon i was trying to make my app send both html+images via javamail, i only managed to send html, but with the image i am having a bit of problems. I decided to create a multipart message, and all was going ok, but then i use the class loader to retrieve the .png file from the WEB-INF/resources/images i get a NullPointerExcetion, i dont know why is that?

Here is how my EJB(3.0) looks like. Ill appreciate a hand on this one i dont have much experience with the ClassLoader class(Dont know much about it).

```
@Stateless(name = "ejbs/EmailServiceEJB")
public class EmailServiceEJB implements IEmailServiceEJB {

@Resource(name = "mail/myMailSession")
private Session mailSession;

public void sendAccountActivationLinkToBuyer(String destinationEmail,
        String name) {

    // Destination of the email
    String to = destinationEmail;
    String from = "dontreply2thismessage@gmail.com";

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        // From: is our service
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        // To: destination given
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Uspijesna registracija");
        // How to found at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0321.html
        message.setContent(generateActivationLinkTemplate(), "text/html");

        Date timeStamp = new Date();
        message.setSentDate(timeStamp);

        // Prepare a multipart HTML
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        // Prepare the HTML
        BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(generateActivationLinkTemplate(), "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        // PREPARE THE IMAGE
        BodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        String fileName = "/WEB-INF/resources/images/logoemailtemplate.png";

        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        if (classLoader == null) {
            classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            if (classLoader == null) {
                System.out.println("IT IS NULL AGAIN!!!!");
            }
        }



        DataSource ds = new URLDataSource(classLoader.getResource(fileName));

        imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
        imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "the-img-1");
        multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
        // Set the message content!
        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

I would like to mention that i am ussing JEE6 with glassfishV3 i dont know if my approach is compatible with this application server.

---

**Update**
When i modify the above code to

```
String fileName = "logoemailtemplate.png";
```

I receive an email, it works.

But now I don't receive the text. :) Is there any mistake?

Comment: Your code is ambiguous. You instantiate a stream but you don't use it in your datasource.

Comment: You are right that stream should not be there, it belongs to old code i used before. A bit of refactor is needed. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're confusing [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) with [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). The former only loads resources from the classpath while the later only loads resources from the webcontent (there where your `/WEB-INF` folder also is).

You need to put those resources in the classpath. If you're using an IDE, then most straightforward way is to just drop them in any package in the Java source folder. It'll end up in `/WEB-INF/classes` after build, which is part of the classpath.

Lets assume that you've a package `com.example.resources.images` and you've dropped `logoemailtemplate.png` file in there, then you can load it by the following `fileName`.

```
String fileName = "/com/example/resources/images/logoemailtemplate.png";
```

An alternative is to add `/WEB-INF/resources` folder to the classpath. In an IDE like Eclipse, you can do that by adding it as *Source folder* in project's build path. Then you can load it by the following `fileName`.

```
String fileName = "/images/logoemailtemplate.png";
```

This is however not the common practice.

Comment: I am starting to understand, i was confused becouse of what i saw in this blog: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/ i thought i had to put all images in the resources folder. But anyway what i am trying now is to add it to a package in the src and then just go to that package in the filename variable. I will try that.

Comment: This tutorial concerns images which are to be displayed in public web, they can be accessed by URL and/or `ExternalContext#getResource()` or analogously `ServletContext#getResource()`. Your question concerns images which are to be included in a mail -that's not part of public web. Also because it's a poor practice to have `javax.servlet` or `javax.faces` imports in an EJB, your best bet is the classpath. You were on the right track already, the file is just at the wrong location :)

Comment: I did it now it is in classpath and it works. Thank you. I recieved an email, but without text, only the image, i suppose i still something missing in my code. But the main problem its solved.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the classLoader can only access WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib but not WEB-INF/resources. Try to put the file in the classes sub-folder.

Comment: Yes but now the variable filename should look like this: String fileName = "logoemailtemplate.png";

Answer (score 0):

You must use [ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to load a file from a war. ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream loads a class from the classpath.

Comment: An EJB doesn't necessarily need to be `ServletContext` aware.

Comment: @BalusC: right, but if it isn't, I don't see how it could get access to the WEB-INF folder of the webapp it's part of. It's a design problem : an EJB is probably not the right place to access WEB-INF.