# How do I stipulate a path to a configuration file from Java in XPages?

Tags: java, xpages

I'm trying to implement the latest version of Apache FOP (version 2.6 at the time of writing) in an XPages app.

Unlike earlier versions, this version reads its configuration from a file. To locate the file there is a line in the Apache FOP example code like this:

```
File xconf = new File("fop.xconf");
FopConfParser parser = new FopConfParser(xconf);
```

Using the Navigator in Domino Designer, I have tried placing the fop.xconf file in a variety of locations inside the database's WEB-INF folder, but when I run the code, I get an error on the server console saying:

> HTTP JVM: java.io.FileNotFoundException: fop.xconf (No such file or directory)

(Note: the the path in the above error message changes depending on what path I put in the code)

I've tried putting a slash in front of the file name, ie. "/fop.xconf" and a dot+slash, ie. "./fop.xconf", but neither worked.

Based upon this page: [Cant retrieve an images from the WEB-INF folder ussing classLoader.getResourceAsStream()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250704/cant-retrieve-an-images-from-the-web-inf-folder-ussing-classloader-getresourceas) I tried adding a folder called "conf" in the WEB-INF folder, and adding the conf folder as a source folder to the build path. Then I modified the path in my code accordingly, ie. I tried "fop.xconf", "/fop.xconf", "conf/fop.xconf", "/conf/fop.xconf", (the last couple in desperation!) but nothing works. I still get the same error.

I also tried using getResourceAsStream but that didn't work either. It seems getResourceAsStream is not compatible with the "File" class, and I'm too much of a novice Java coder to know why.

How do I stipulate the path? Do I need to place the fop.xconf file in another folder somewhere in the database?

Comment: Try placing the file in the Code/Java folder where your XPages Java code is

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response, Per. I put the file in the Code/Java folder as you suggested but the code fails with the same "No such file or directory" error.